# Bash scripting help ENV_NAME=${1:-develop}

Tags: bash, shell

I've inherited some bash scripts and I see this one liner

```
ENV_NAME=${1:-develop}
```

Can someone tell me what it's doing? I don't even know how to google this.

Thanks!

Comment: Open `man bash` and search on `:-`.  (In other words, run `man bash` and type `/:-<return>`)

Comment: If you google `site:stackoverflow.com bash colon dash`, you find **several** instances of this question.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe is also a great resource

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet as well -- if you search for `:-` in that page, you've got a definition.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Dup-voting it was definitely the way to go here. Good point.

Comment: Here is the page link on the best `bash` manual I saw: [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: @frist, the ABS is an abominably poor resource -- it makes a habit of using bad practices in its examples, so people who learned from it often need to have such practices they picked up by example trained out of them. Please do not encourage its use.

Answer (score 0):

The construct is a so called [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). It expands to a default value if the variable itself is not set or null. The semantic is

```
${variable:-default value}
```

`$1` is  the first parameter passed to the script. If the parameter will be omitted `ENV_NAME` defaults to `"develop"`.